# MVC save two Models

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, model

I have a problem that's probably easy to fix, but I don't find the right way to do it.

I have the following situation:
I am building a web application where I use several forms. One of the forms uses and displays two Entity Framework models that have a 1:1 relation. It's one entity for all *BaseData* (common Data) and one entity for *AdditionalData* (specific Data). The form's Model is of type *AdditionalData*, which has a NavigationProperty of type *BaseData*.

When I want to save this "form" i.e. the two entities - what is the best way to do that?

- Do I call two Actions seperately, like "Save(BaseData) then Save(AdditionalData)"(how?)?
- Do I redirect from one Save Action to the Other one (also how?)?
- Do I need to build a new Model to accomplish what I need (maybe with a special ModelBinder) or do I only need a special ModelBinder?
- Can I manually invoke the ModelBinder for the "BaseData" manually from the Save Action of the AddidionalDataController?

Am I doing it completely wrong in the first place?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Create a ViewModel specific to the View which contains both of the models. When you submit the form it will post the VM which contains both of the models. Update both of the models one by one from the VM.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will give it a try